# Why pointer is returning String and not the first char since pointer is storing address of first char only?

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers, char

I am new to C++. As per my knowledge in the above case `names[0]` should be the index of `'R'`.
I guess I am missing out or lacking knowledge.
Please help me.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char *names[] = {
            "Rohan",
            "Sammy",
            "Samuel",
            "Henil"
    };

    // Expected R to be printed and not Rohan
    cout << *names << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Rohan
```

Comment: `names` is an array. So, in `*names` `names` has decayed to a pointer. Hence, it has a type of `char**`.

Comment: FYI, your code does not compile in C++11 and later, because you can't assign a string literal to a non-const `char*`.  Use `const char*` instead: `const char* names[] = {"Rohan", ...};`

Answer (score 0):

> As per my knowledge of in the above case names[0] should be the index of 'R'

`names[0]` is not an index. It is a pointer. It points to the char `R` within the string literal.

When a pointer is inserted into a character stream, the behaviour is not to stream the pointed object.

When you insert a pointer to char into a character stream, it is assumed to be a pointer to null terminated string and the behaviour is to streamed the entire string. You should adjust your expectations accordingly.

P.S. The program is ill-formed since C++11 because string literals are not implicitly convertible to `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put brackets *names[0]

**[CODE]:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char* names[] = {
        "Rohan",
        "Sammy",
        "Samuel",
        "Henil"
    };
   
       
    //   Expected R to be printed and not Rohan
       cout<<*names[0]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**[RESULT]:**

> `R`

[Live demo here!](https://onlinegdb.com/rkQzVqc9P)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to an array by name will *decay* to a pointer to the 1st element of the array.  So, `names` is the same as `&names[0]`, and thus `*names` is the same as `names[0]`, which is the 1st `char*` element in the array, not the 1st `char` of the 1st string in the array.